# Is it worth picking up blues on a farming run in Act I Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just saw a video where a Wizard farmed yellows in Act I killing as many Elites as fast as possible. He only picked up the rare items, no blues, no gems etc. Just gold and yellows / uniques.

I usually do something similar, but I pick up blues and other goodies, like gems, as well.
Usually the blues are not that good, but I still check and vendor them.

Here is my question: Is it worth picking up blues on such runs or is counter productive as the time invested could be used to farm even more yellows?

This is all assuming you can survive in higher Acts and you just crush everything in Act I.

Comment: Act II blues are generally better than Act I blues. So yes, if you crush everything in Act I then it's really unlikely that an Act I blue will be better than any gear you have already and you should focus on yellows.

Comment: Actually, I didn't consider the gold value of blues. Read the answers they elaborate nicely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since patch 1.0.3 there is a chance you get ilvl 63 items, so blue items can be worth a lot when you are lucky. I for myself always pickup ALL the blue items which let me make a lot of gold simply by selling all the useless stuff.

I sort them in my inventory as I pick them up so that items with ilvl 61+ start in the lower right corner of my inventory, everything that I sell on AH I put in the lower left corner and all the stuff to sell to the merchant start in the top right corner. When my inventory is full I can rush to city, sell all the stuff that's useless, salvage all the ilvl 61+ items at the blacksmith (they give the highest materials) and put the items to sell on AH in my stash.

Sure you lose a bit of time, but that way I make an extra 100-200k gold each hour which can be very important especially if you didn't find any 10 million gold items yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Act I blues now have a 2% chance to be iLvl 63 - and hence could be of use / sold on the AH.

Rares have a tendency to be better, but I'd simply hold in my CTRL button while hovering over items while on the ground, and just pick up the items that have reqlvl 60 or rings/amu/follower items reqlvl 59+ for disenchanting.

ref( http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/Patch_103_Design_Preview-6_6_2012#blog )